# Bazel installation error when attempting to install TensorFlow from source

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

Thank you for your time. Recently, in order to use TensorFlow as the software for an experiment, I have, as outlined in the "Install from Source" guide provided by TensorFlow, attempted to install the Bazel program. However, I hav reached an error. The issue here is the fact that after downloading the Bazel installer file, I ran the command provided in step 3 of "Install Bazel" (provided by Bazel), but was provided with the messages:

```
-bash: 0.21.0: No such file or directory
```

or:

```
chmod: bazel-0.21.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory
```

(first time)

or:

```
chmod: ./bazel-0.21.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory
```

(first time)

I have been unable to solve the issue. The installer file, when clicked, opened in Xcode as a saved file, but has not registered in the terminal. Thank you for any assistance one could provide. Have a Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. 
Make sure you are in the same directory as the installer file in order to be able to make the file executable and then installing it.
You can do this by simply running the following command in a terminal window:

```
cd <directory of the .sh installer file>
chmod +x bazel-0.21.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
./bazel-0.21.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user
```